# Mysql: Can't use a subquery field as a condition?

Tags: mysql

This code runs fine. Pay special attention to the 'AS commercial' subquery field. It works.

```
SELECT `Contacts`.`id`,
    (
        SELECT `team_members`.`id`
        FROM team_members
        INNER JOIN team_categories_team_members AS memcat
            ON `team_members`.`id` = `memcat`.`team_member_id`
        WHERE `memcat`.`team_category_id` =3
    ) AS commercial
    FROM `oys001`.`team_members` AS `Contacts`
    JOIN `oys001`.`brands_team_members` AS `BrandsTeamMember` ON ( 
        `BrandsTeamMember`.`brand_id` =2
        AND `BrandsTeamMember`.`team_member_id` = `Contacts`.`id` )
```

However, now I want to perform a condition on it, so I just add this:

```
 WHERE commercial > 0
```

And it tells me the field does not exist... What's going wrong here?

Comment: It's not a real field, it's a computed value that's been aliased. Instead of using `WHERE`, use keyword `HAVING` - `HAVING commercial > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your inital query in brackets

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM (yourqueryhere) AS `v`
 WHERE commercial > 0
```